# Continuously writing output from Linux command to file

Tags: linux, perl

I want to write data obtained through a command (Linux) to a file. But, I don't want the file to get overwritten (which seems to happen with Perl scripts I've written thus far). I want the file to update every time my Perl script is executed (which I'm going to set up through crontab). The following script is what I have thus far (and it doesn't do what I'd like):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open FH, ">sysdata.csv";
print FH `ps -e | wc -l`;
print FH "\n";
close FH;
```

**This script overwrites the file sysdata.csv every time it gets executed. So I need help on how to make this file just get updated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already got the answer put please check out this too to improve your code: http://perlmaven.com/always-use-3-argument-open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using >> instead of > will do an append to file rather than an overwrite

Comment: Thanks! That was a very simple fix